# Synchronized block in Singleton Pattern (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, volatile

I have a question regarding a thread-safe Singleton pattern I found on Wikipedia.

```
public final class Singleton {

    private static volatile Singleton instance = null;

    private Singleton() {}

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized(Singleton.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new Singleton();
                }
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

If the synchronized block wasn't synchronized, would it be possible for 2 threads to create 2 objects simultaneously?

I need to explain the usage of "synchronized" for an assignment.

Thanks and best regards

Comment: "thread-safe" it's not entirely safe. Another thread can synchronize on `Singleton.class` and cause the thread calling `getInstance()` to block indefinitely. Far simpler, more robust approaches exist (e.g. enum or lazy holder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it wasn't synchronized, you could indeed have 2 threads create 2 objects.

- T1: checks if instance is null => yes! => continues to next line
- T2: checks if instance is null => yes! => continues to next line
- T1: creates object
- T2: creates object

While using synchronized, only 1 thread can enter the synchronized blocked at a time.

- T1: checks if instance is null => yes! => continues to next line
- T1: creates object
- T2: checks if instance is null => no! => skips block

Edit:

> It is worth noting that the null check inside of the synchronized
>   block is actually very important - otherwise it would be possible to
>   create 2 objects as well. – Amongalen (in comments)

Another way to achieve a Singleton pattern is the following. **Only use this pattern if creating the object isn't a big problem to do as soon as the application starts:**

```
public final class Singleton {

    private static Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    private Singleton() {}

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is worth noting that the null check inside of the synchronized block is actually very important - otherwise it would be possible to create 2 objects as well.